# How to configure an endpoint in Spring to accept both form data and XML request body?

Tags: data-binding, spring-mvc

I have a small question regarding Spring's MVC data binding capabilities.
I do have the following controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController() {

    // … some init stuff //

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit.{format}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editFoo(@RequestBody FooItem foo, @PathVariable("format") String format) {

        // some code here to edit the FooItem //
    }
}
```

I want to be able to post form data as well as XML against this method. For that to work I added two message converters to my `applicationContext.xml`: The default `formHttpMessageConverter` and an XStream marshaller.

This works fine, but I have a problem, that if I use `@RequestBody` and post form data against the URL, the server responds with a 415 Error. If I remove this annotation, form data works well and Spring creates the object for me, but if I post XML against it, I get an empty object.

Is there any way around this or do I need to have 2 methods to be able to handle both of the incoming formats?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you post form data? Are you sure that request has a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header?

Comment: data is posted with standard HTML form, so the
Content-Type header shows "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two methods.

`FormHttpMessageConverter` doesn't have the same databinding capabilities as  `@ModelAttribute` provides, it can't bind request to the specified target class, only to `MultiValueMap` (see [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html)).

Comment: sounds reasonable, as the FormHttpMessageConverter is only able to return a MultiValueMap (as you've written).

Comment: This solution does work, but it requires an extra endpoint (`/foo` for XML and `/foo/bar` for form data). I see how a filter on the request structure could help segregate requests and exposing a single endpoint (e.g. body or not body), but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward approach. And yes, this is an old post. Working on legacy code~